# What is being implied when asked there is a one too many relationship between two tables?

Tags: php, sql

I have an sql related question that is asking the following.

Write a SQL query that returns the first name and last name as a string with last name first then first name of people that have been called more than once in the last month given that:

•   **There is a one to many relationship between the table t_people and the table t_calls**

•   The call_date field in t_calls is a datetime field

•   The last_name field is a varchar

•   The first_name field is a varchar

```
$query = "SELECT last_name, first_name from t_people"; // little confused based upon my question

$result = $mysqli->query($query)
```

Comment: It means that for any one uniquely identified row in `t_people` (one person), there may be one _or more_ associated rows in `t_calls`. But a row in `t_calls` can belong to/be associated with only _one_ `t_people` row.  `t_calls` should have a column like `people_id` or similar which is a foreign key back to `t_people`.

Comment: If you counted up the rows in `t_calls`, there would be multiple rows per `people_id` (or whatever the foreign key column is)

Comment: This tutsplus page has some diagrams representing the relationships http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT last_name, first_name from t_people p
    JOIN t_calls c ON (
        p.people_id = c.people_id -- I just assume that is the foreign key
        AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < c.call_date
    )
```